# React animation synchronization

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animate.css

I have the following React component:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            visibility: 'visible'
        };
    },

    toggleState: function() {
        if (this.state.visibility === 'visible') {
            this.setState({visibility: 'hidden'});
        } else {
            this.setState({visibility: 'visible'});
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
        var self = this;
        setInterval(function() {
            self.toggleState();
        }, 5000);
    },

    render: function() {
        return <div className={"animated " + (this.state.visibility === 'visible' ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut')}>{this.state.visibility}</div>;
    }

});
```

See the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/acasaccia/69z2wepo/50309/).

Basically I am controlling both the string displayed and the component visibility using [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) through the `state` property `visibility`.

Side effect is that, when the component is fading out, it shows "hidden" and then starts hiding. I would like to start the animation earlier, and only once it's done, change the string, so that "hidden" is never actually displayed.

What's the best way to achieve this kind of synchronization?

Comment: I believe the best way is to listen for a 'animationend' event. Here is updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/50313/

Comment: Interesting. Where do you get that `animationend` event from? Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: It's just a part of css3-animations spec. I mean nothing special, just a native event. Be aware to add vendor prefixes to it if it's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to change state after hiding animation completed is to listen for a `animationend` event. Since you need to change text state only when your component has `hidden` visibility state you should change it right after hiding animation complete and change back to `visible` on start animation.

Extend `state` with `text`:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    visibility: 'visible',
    text: 'visible'
  }
}
```

So you should add listener in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  this.refs.animated.addEventListener('animationend', this.toggleText); // add ref="animated" element
  // rest code
}
```

Add `toggleText` method to change text state on animationend:

```
toggleText: function() {
  if (this.state.visibility === 'hidden') { // change only on hidden state
    this.setState({
      text: 'hidden'
    });
  }
```

}

And change text to `visible` right on show animation start, so:

```
toggleState: function() {
  if (this.state.visibility === 'visible') {
    this.setState({visibility: 'hidden'}); // text should not be changed immediately
  } else {
    this.setState({visibility: 'visible', text: 'visible'}); // change the text on show animation start
  }
```

}

Here's completed [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/50324/)

Comment: I like the idea, if you write a proper answer (include only relevant code, explain what changes you did) I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use a `ref` to "manually" synchronize the component's text and visibility with `setTimeout`:

```
render: function() {
  return <div ref="hello">visible</div>;
}

componentWillUpdate: function(next_props, next_state) {
  var self = this;
  if (next_state.visibility === 'visible') {
    this.refs.hello.className = 'animated fadeIn';
    this.refs.hello.innerHTML = 'visible';
  } else {
    this.refs.hello.className = 'animated fadeOut';
    setTimeout(function(){
      self.refs.hello.innerHTML = 'hidden';
    }, 1000);
  }
},
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/acasaccia/69z2wepo/50315/).